# Cannot allow a not root user to create an Upstart event

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I am trying to allow a not root user to create an Upstart-event. So the only thing this user should do with Upstart is to create an event.

As far as I understand, I can grant some privileges in Upstart.conf. But unfortunately I was not able to find how to solve my problem. Could you please help me?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution is to add the users in sudo to only be allowed to run the upstart commands you specify.

Users in the adm group would be able to do below:

%adm ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/start app, /sbin/stop app

But replace with the commands you want to restrict them to.